# Can you assign a value only if its greater / less than the current value?

Tags: c#, operators

I'm wondering if there's an operator to simplify this? 
Similar to the += operator.

```
if (x > val) x = val;
x "new operator" val;


//date times
DateTime d1 = dsi_curr.cycleSteps.StepsUpTimestamp[0] ;
DateTime d2 = dsi_curr.cycleSteps.StepsUpTimestamp[dsi_curr.cycleSteps.StepsUpTimestamp.Length-1];

if (d1 < curbt.details.StartDate) {
    curbt.details.StartDate = d1;
}
if (d2 > curbt.details.EndDate) {
    curbt.details.EndDate = d2;
}
```

Comment: if you dont want to write 'if' word you can use ternary operator: `x = x > val ? val : x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin operator for this, but you can add your own method to simplify this:

```
static void MakeLesserOf(ref DateTime self, DateTime other) {
    self = self > other ? other : self;
}
static void MakeGreaterOf(ref DateTime self, DateTime other) {
    self = self < other ? other : self;
}
```

Now you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
MakeLesserOf(curbt.details.StartDate, d1);
MakeGreaterOf(curbt.details.EndDate, d2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in an unnecessary assignment operation if your condition is false

Comment: @bit2know Yes, it would, but for all practical purposes it would not matter.

Comment: Perhaps its not an issue when you create a dedicated method to perform this operation, but IMO when I see code that performs an unnecessary operation that doesn't add the the readability of the code I question if that was what the programmer intended to do

Comment: I think this is the best way, either with a method like this, or an extension method, or a property.

Comment: @Rhett I thought of an extension method too. Unfortunately, C# does not let you write extension methods that take their first argument by reference, forcing you to do an assignment: `curbt.details.StartDate = curbt.details.StartDate.LesserOf(d1);` I didn't want to write `curbt.details.StartDate` twice, so I went with a regular static method.

Answer (score 2):

For simple types you can use `Math.Min()` and `Math.Max()`, but not with DateTime.

It will still do the assignment, but it will re-assign the lower/higher value.

Comment: It's easy to write an `Min`/`Max` equivalent for DateTime though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to simplify your conditional expressions, you can use the [conditional operator (?:)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) as mentioned by [JleruOHeP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300049/jleruohep) in the comments.

```
curbt.details.StartDate = (d1 < curbt.details.StartDate) ? d1 : curbt.details.StartDate;
curbt.details.EndDate = (d2 > curbt.details.EndDate) ? d2 : curbt.details.EndDate;
```

Though in this particular case I would just write the `if` without the linebreaks:

```
if (d1 < curbt.details.StartDate) curbt.details.StartDate = d1;
if (d2 > curbt.details.EndDate) curbt.details.EndDate = d2;
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.